# In Android How do I set an image to a imageView of different activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onclick, imageview

I want to change the background of an imageView to an image that I have in a gallery of another class. So far I have the Main activity with a imageView that shows one of the pictures by defualt, and I would like to change that image to another from the gallery that I created on another activity OnClick.

Thanks,

Here the two activities:

Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageSelected"
    android:background="@drawable/brien"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ButtonChangePic"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/changePic"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonChangePic"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="146dp"
    android:onClick="changePicture"/>
```

Main.java

```
package com.gallery.brien.picturegallery;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class Main extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void changePicture(View view) {
    // Open picture gallery activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PictureGallery.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

Gallery

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class PictureGallery extends Activity {

//variable array where pictures are store
Integer[] Profile = {R.drawable.brien, R.drawable.kick, R.drawable.mma, R.drawable.fun,
        R.drawable.run};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.picture_gallery);

    //  UI of gallery display. Initializes the GridView and ItemView
    //  classes. Then wait for interaction from user.
    GridView gal = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSelected);

    //  Calls the ImageAdapter Class.
    gal.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    // Calls the onItemClickListener Class
    gal.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override

       /*                onItemClick Method
       The onItemClick method has four arguments.
        AdapterView<?> arg0 - Records where the user touched screen
        View arg1 - Parameters of the View user touched
        int arg2  - Integer value that holds the position of the View
                    in the adapter.
        long arg3 - Determines the row id of the item that was
                     selected by the user.
        */
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected picture " + (arg2)
                    + " Brien Calloway", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageView.setImageResource(Profile[arg2]);



        }
    });


}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        context=c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {return Profile.length;}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView pic = new ImageView(context);
        pic.setImageResource(Profile[arg0]);
        pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        pic.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,175));
        return pic;

    }
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_picture_gallery, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the selected picture from `Gallery` to `Main`, you should use [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) instead of `startActivity()`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should be using preferences for this. You can store the int for the resourceID in a preferences object. When you load the main activity you'll attempt to fetch that preferences value and then change the background image to that.

In your gallery, when the user selects an image, you'll save the resource id as a preference.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   int resourceId = settings.getInt("backgroundImage", DEFAULT_VALUE);

   // Now use that ID to set the background 
}

....
```

}

```
public class PictureGallery extends Activity {
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
           ...
           SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
           editor.putBoolean("backgroundImage", DEFAULT_VALUE);

          // Commit the edits!
          editor.commit();
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html for more information about utilizing shared preferences.

Edit: This solution will allow selections to persist between launches of the app. You will permanently change the background. If you just want to temporarily change it, then as another answer suggested, you want to use startActivityForResult